# search function advise

Tags: android

I have a folder with pictures and I'd like to make a search function to be able to find pictures that correspond to their key words.
I'd like to know how you'd do this ?

I thought making a *.txt file with the name of the pictures and their corresponding key words, and then search in this text file the key words asked.

Is there a simpler way ? A better FileType (for instance *.ini) ?

Could you give me an advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple sqlite database and query it with your keyword.

There are many Android Sqlite sample out in Google to get an idea how it works.
Also see the Android dev docs
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Answer (score 0):

Is it an option that pictures contain file property -> tag and that you enter keywords to that property so you can search pictures by tags?

That way your picture will contain the keywords itself and that way there is no need to create extra files.

Just an idea...